# A larger version of a symmetric unit figure is $n^2$ times the unit figure - is this mathematically provable or is there a postulate?

Tags: geometry, area

Is there a postulate that states that any symmetric figure ( I have found it works for squares, parallelograms, rectangles, triangles and if you consider just the area, hexagons, pentagons, circles, etc) that has a feature that is n times the feature of a unit figure (side(s) or radius), has an area equal to $n^2$ times that of the unit figure? (aspect ratio, angles to be maintained for rectangles and parallelograms). It is intuitive from the individual formulae for the respective areas, but is there a more elegant universal proof/postulate? [Equilateral triangles whose sides are 2, 3, 4 times that of the unit triangle have 4, 9, 16 triangles respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j11Qx.jpg)

Comment: If you double the side of a square, you get a bigger square made of 4 squares equal to the original one, so the area is multiplied by $2^2=4$. You can generalize it to multiplying the side by $N$, then the area multiplies by $N^2$. Beyond that, it depends on your formal definition of area for arbitrary shapes, but basically you can think of covering them with many small squares then reduce the problem to one about squares.

Comment: This can be proved, but it takes some advanced definitions for area in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

There is an intuitive proof for this. For this we can simply consider that perimeters are linear in dimension while areas are quadratic. Now, scaling a figure is as good as considering a figure that is similar to it (Note that this is not the intuitive similar, this is the mathematical similar). As the figures are similar, the dimensions are a multiple of the dimensions of the unit figure that is 1. Thus areas would be $n^2$ times the original, because areas are quadratic. Similarly, perimeters would be $n$ times because perimeter function is invariably linear in dimension.

Comment: ?Would this mean $n^3$ for 3 dimensional object scaling

Comment: As long as you scale all dimensions by the same factor and the similarity is maintained, we can claim that the factor for three dimensional object should be $n^3$. For more clarity, you can refer to the formulas for common shapes like cube, sphere, etc. The formulas for volumes are third order in dimension.